# Highcharts - outside text index label

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this chart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels. How could I put the text from the index label outsaid columns.Thank you!

Comment: Datalabels are positioned outside of the columns by default. Put up a fiddle of your actual chart with your actual code if you need actual help.

Comment: @Abhijit Jagtap, the question is correct, Randolph Abeyta understood the question and answered correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to move the labels from within the columns to outside, correct?

Unfortunately, those values from inside the column are not index labels, but dataLabels. So they are representing the values of the columns. I moved them by modifying the x property int the "dataLabels" section of the high chart. You can view how I did it at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cpnq5fou/

```
 dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            x: 12, //12 pixels to move it to the right of the column, instead of inside
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answered!